# Grep в чем ошибка регулярного выражения

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, xml, grep

```
grep -oE '<node[\s\p{L}\w\"=\-\.\,\:\/\[\]]*focused="true"[\s\p{L}\w\"=\-\.\,\:\/\[\]]*\/>' window_dump.xml
```

Должно найти:

```
<node index="1" text="Поиск игр и приложений" resource-id="com.android.vending:id/search_bar_hint" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.android.vending" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="true" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[194,102][780,150]" />
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: а зачем здесь `<node[` квадратная скобка. Похоже, что там круглая нужна (ну и парная ей)

Comment: Из-за `Поиск игр и приложений`

Comment: А почему не сделано так: `grep -oE '<node.*?focused="true".*?\/>'`?

Comment: @Joker это не одно и то же

Comment: @dIm0n Это понятно, непонятно, был ли смысл переусложнять.

Comment: @dIm0n для этого я вставлял \p{L}

Comment: @Joker я попробовал ваш вариант, не помогло.

Comment: В принципе всё делаете неправильно, а именно используете регулярные выражения для _XML_. Не надо так делать. Есть _xmlgrep_, если не ошибаюсь, для подобных извращений. https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmlgrep

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/18466/grep-tool-for-xml

Answer (score -1):

Немного подумав, я сам нашёл решение.

grep -oE '<[^<>]*focused="true"[^<>]*>' window_dump.xml

Comment: Но это решение никак не следует из условия задания, надо было привести больше примеров. Прочитайте описание метки [tag:регулярные-выражения]